# Can Core Data be seen on an iPad without running the app that uses it?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, ios6

I am creating an app that uses Core Data. I would like to know if, once the app is loaded on the iPad, is the data secure within the app or can the data be viewed outside of running the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the SQLite persistent store can easily be viewed using PhoneView or some similar desktop applications, combined with command-line SQLite or any other SQLite front-end application.

Now other features like iOS's encryption using the lock code may provide some security for the owner of the device's data, but Core Data won't provide additional protection. If that's not your concern, but rather preventing users from understanding the data model, then you must realize that to decrypt a file that's on the device you must at some point have the key in memory on the device - and any determined individual will be able to get that key via Jailbreaking or a number of other techniques.

Comment: As stated here, unless you integrate your own methods of devious hiding and encryptions, you're relying on iOS's encryptions and the idea of the sandboxed application files.

Comment: @TheGamingArt I like the phrasing of that, thank you for the comment. I'd also add that, in my view and least theoretically, you can't really treat your application and the user as separate parties for the purpose of encryption.

Comment: Thanks you for such a quick answer. My reason for asking is that I have to store a code (a user code if you like) the first time that the app is run. I then want this to be fixed and not accessed again. I am looking at the best way to do this and thought an entity in core data might be the solution.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths if you are hoping to prevent the user from tampering with that code then obfuscation is your best bet but it is not truly 'secure' but rather an impediment.

Comment: Someone suggested storing the username in the plist. Would this make sense?

Comment: @RichardGriffiths if you mean to store in the app's Info.plist then anyone will see it and anyone with a jailbroken device will be able to modify it.

Comment: Thanks - no easy answer then. Appreciate your help.